Trying to extract live data from mt5 to my python script but getting data 10 hours old not realtime
# Fetch historical bars for a specific symbol and time range
def get_bars(symbol, timeframe, start_date, end_date):
    if not mt5.symbol_select(symbol, True):
        print(f"Failed to select symbol: {symbol}")
        return None
    
    rates = mt5.copy_rates_range(symbol, timeframe, start_date, end_date)



output generated by code 

Date: 2024-07-23 08:30:00, Type: Bullish, Gap: 31.44, First High: 66655.37, Third Low: 66686.81
Date: 2024-07-23 08:33:00, Type: Bullish, Gap: 105.20, First High: 66741.48, Third Low: 66846.68
Date: 2024-07-23 09:30:00, Type: Bullish, Gap: 3.41, First High: 66917.66, Third Low: 66921.07
Date: 2024-07-23 09:33:00, Type: Bullish, Gap: 25.20, First High: 66974.76, Third Low: 66999.96
Date: 2024-07-23 10:48:00, Type: Bearish, Gap: 24.62, First Low: 66936.30, Third High: 66911.68
Date: 2024-07-23 11:03:00, Type: Bearish, Gap: 79.14, First Low: 66829.84, Third High: 66750.70
Date: 2024-07-23 11:24:00, Type: Bearish, Gap: 40.32, First Low: 66610.38, Third High: 66570.06
Date: 2024-07-23 11:33:00, Type: Bullish, Gap: 37.54, First High: 66613.56, Third Low: 66651.10
    
    if rates is None:
        print(f"Failed to get rates for symbol: {symbol}")
        return None
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(rates)
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')  # Convert Unix timestamp to datetime
    return df

also this is in the main function
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()  # Get the current time
        end_date = now  # Use current time as end_date
        start_date = now - timedelta(days=1)  # Look back 1 day for data

this is the snippet of data extractions but its only extracting data which 5-10 hours not the realtime please help me outa here
please help me if i am doing something wrong

Are you, perhaps, in a timezone that is 10 hours away from GMT?

i am 5:30 + from gmt

How do you know the data is 10 hours old?  What are you using to make that determination?  I'm thinking that you're actually getting the correct data, but you're converting the timestamp incorrectly.

let me show you here isDate: 2024-07-23 07:24:00, Type: Bearish, Gap: 24.84, First Low: 66564.65, Third High: 66539.81
thisis the most recent data that system can fetch

ive added output in the main post please chekc

Well, that doesn't tell me anything.  If you just ran that, those dates are from 4 days ago.

that is the most recent date i can get

basically i am calculating FVG and print them into terminal of last 7 days from current time

I'm trying to GUIDE you into debugging this.  Either you are not sending the date/time you think you are, or there is a timezone confusion, or their service doesn't send real-time data for free accounts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use copy_rates_from(symbol, timeframe, fromDate, number_of_data) instead of copy_rates_range when the fromDate have to equal to datetime.now() for your purpose and the number_of_data can equal to number of data that you need(e.g. 1000). If the problem is solved, your issue is the time zone.
